# iOS action extension how to get a small image

Tags: ios, objective-c

In system photo library, open my action extension, because image is too big, extension crashed, how can I get a smaller image?

I try to use this following code, but it not work.

```
NSDictionary * dict =@{NSItemProviderPreferredImageSizeKey:[NSValue valueWithCGSize:CGSizeMake(300, 300)]};
[itemProvider loadItemForTypeIdentifier:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage options:dict completionHandler:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error) {

}];
```

Comment: check image size after selecting it and if require so reduce the size so may be it will help you out , in above case if you are guessing this is the issue

Comment: it is crashed when loading image, there is no chance to reduce it. so it must get a smaller image when loading...

Answer (score 0):

Before load the image on imageView. First resize it. Then load the resized image on imageView.

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:selectedImgdata];
selectedImage = [self resizeImage:img];
```

Resize image Data:

```
-(UIImage *)resizeImage :(UIImage *)theImage
{
    if((theImage.size.width > 1024 && theImage.size.height > 768) || (theImage.size.width > 768 && theImage.size.height > 1024) || (theImage.size.width > 1024 && theImage.size.height < 768) || (theImage.size.height > 1024 && theImage.size.width < 768))
    {
        float newHeight,newWidth,oldWidth,oldHeight,scaleFactor;

        if(theImage.size.width > theImage.size.height)
        {
            oldWidth = theImage.size.width;
            scaleFactor = 1024 / oldWidth;

            newHeight = theImage.size.height * scaleFactor;
            newWidth = oldWidth * scaleFactor;
        }
        else
        {
            oldHeight = theImage.size.height;
            scaleFactor = 1024 / oldHeight;

            newWidth = theImage.size.width * scaleFactor;
            newHeight = oldHeight * scaleFactor;
        }

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(newWidth, newHeight), NO, 1.0);
        [theImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newWidth, newHeight)];
        UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        return newImage;
    }
    return theImage;
}
```

Comment: It will be memory overload before the image load in, so should have a method to load a smaller image before action extension start.